# Как посчитать сумму в блоках

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

Мне нужно посчитать сумму во всех `span`. У меня не получается получить каждое число по отдельности. Подскажите какими методами это можно сделать?
Заранее спасибо!

```js
let total = 0;
// Преобразую сроку в число
let price = parseInt($('.list > p > .price').text())

//Но на выходе получаются 345
console.log(price)

//Вывожу в html
$('.total').html("Сумма " + (total + price))
```

```html
<div class='list'>
  <p>Цена <span class="price">3</span></p>
  <p>Цена <span class="price">4</span></p>
  <p>Цена <span class="price">5</span></p>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а всё потому, что в блоках находится СТРОКА, а не число. И операция получается не сложение, а конкатенация строк.  Есть даже [мем](https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/u_2d2e012e71e1b0e750e801b70252d6f7_800.jpg)

Comment: @ArchDemon, автор парсит число из строки, посмотри на код - в нем есть `parseInt`. Просто он **не ту строку** парсит... то есть, тут банально незнание принципа работы жучкометода `text`.

Comment: Дай бог вам всем здоровья, да ЗП по больше))
Выручили!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) без аргументов - возвращает **объединенное** текстовое содержимое всех элементов jQuery-коллекции, в контексте которой вызван.
И это, в данном случае, значение `'345'` (метод взял из элементов строки их содержимого `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'` - и соединил их в одну строку).

Для суммирования элементов коллекций (массивов и приводимых к массиву данных), в JS обычно применяют метод [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const total = $('.list > p > .price').toArray().reduce(
  (rslt, el) => rslt + parseInt($(el).text())    // или rslt + +($(el).text())
, 0); 
$('.total').text('Сумма ' + total);
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <p>Цена <span class="price">3</span></p>
  <p>Цена <span class="price">4</span></p>
  <p>Цена <span class="price">5</span></p>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

У jQuery есть методы `map` и `each` аналогичные стандартным методам объекта `Array`, но нет метода аналогичного стандартному `reduce`. Поэтому приводим коллекцию к массиву элементов методом `toArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Я не специалист в jQuery. На чистом JS я сделал бы так:

```
const prices = [...document.querySelectorAll('span.price')]
const res = prices.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc += +el.textContent
  return acc
}, 0)

document.querySelector('.total').textContent = 'Сумма ' + res
```